# Extract Variables from a serialized JSON-Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract the three variables (`friendCount`, `pnCount`, and `allCount`) out of a string representation of the following Object:

```
'{"friendCount":5,"pnCount":0,"allCount":5}'
```

I thought about using a RegEx or similar, but I have no further Idea. The numbers in the string may be between 0 and about 100

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If that is a string, than parse it...

```
var str = '{"friendCount":5,"pnCount":0,"allCount":5}';
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(obj.friendCount, obj.pnCount, obj.allCount);
```

If it is already an object, just reference it

```
var obj = {"friendCount":5,"pnCount":0,"allCount":5};
console.log(obj.friendCount, obj.pnCount, obj.allCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var data= {"friendCount":5,"pnCount":0,"allCount":5}

var friendCount = data.friendCount;
var pnCount = data.pnCount;
var allCount = data.allCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want Regex it can be done like [this](https://regex101.com/r/sI2lB8/6):

```
var re = /([\w]+)":(\d+)/g; 
var str = '"friendCount":5,"pnCount":0,"allCount":5';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
```

}